# Explanation of '+' string operator in Python

Tags: python

This is Python code to try different list operations. I don't understand it. Could someone explain the + operator in expression `cmd+="("+",".join(arg)+")"` from the code below?

```
n = int(raw_input())
l=[]
for _ in range(n):
    s=raw_input().split()
    cmd=s[0]
    arg=s[1:]
    if cmd!='print':
        cmd+="("+",".join(arg)+")"
        eval("l."+cmd)
    else:
        print l
```

Inputs:

```
insert 0 5
insert 1 10
insert 0 6
print
```

Comment: Which ‘+’ are you referring to?

Comment: String formatting is great for readability. Consider this `cmd+=f"({",".join(arg)})"` or `cmd+="({})".format(",".join(arg))` or `cmd+="(%s)" % ",".join(arg)`. Does that make it clearer what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

The + in the expression you want is concatenate. It takes (  concatenates it  with every element of arg. The "," is for the join method and the parantheses are for all the exprension. For example if you have arg = [1,2,3] then  "("+,",".join(arg)+")" gives you (1,2,3) and this is a string if instead you had ("+,"k".join(arg)+")" it would give you (1k2k3k) . In general concatenate "merge's" strings together. In python since everything is an object + has a meaning sometimes besides addition. For more info search concatenate python.

EDIT: I assume you mean this + because the += is cmd = cmd +

Answer (score 0):

If both sides of the `+` operator are strings, the operator does concatenation. That is, `"foo" + "bar"` becomes `"foobar"`.

In the code you show, there are a whole bunch of different concatenations. First some parentheses are concatenated onto both ends of a string returned from `str.join` (which puts commas in between the strings in `args`), then you concatenate that whole thing onto the end of the `cmd` string. Finally you concatenate all of `cmd` to `l.` before you eval it.

So for your example input of `insert 0 5`, `cmd` starts as `"insert"`, `args` starts as the list `["0", "5"]`. You first create `"0, 5"` from `join`, then concatenate the parentheses to get `"(0, 5)"` then concatenate onto `cmd` to get `"insert(0, 5)"`, and finally `"l.insert(0, 5)"`.

As [kojiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418413/kojiro) commented, using string formatting rather than concatenation would make this a lot clearer. There are several methods of formatting you could use. The best for you is probably the `str.format` method (which works as far back as Python 2.6, though you should really consider upgrading to Python 3, since Python 2 is now past its end-of-life date):

```
s=raw_input().split()
cmd=s[0]
arg=s[1:]
if cmd!='print':
    formatted = "l.{0}({1})".format(cmd, ",".join(rest))
    eval(formatted)
else:
    print l
```